# Does the New Testament mention Christians worshipping the Holy Spirit?

Tags: new-testament, pneumatology, worship

The New Testament often mentions Christians worshipping God the Father, as well as His only-begotten Son, the Lord Jesus Christ ([John 5:23](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&b=Jhn&c=5&v=1&x=0&y=0#conc/23)). However, does the New Testament mention Christians worshipping the Holy Spirit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The New Testament does not explicitly mention worshipping the Holy Spirit as it does God the Father and His only-begotten Son. However, it does mention worshipping the Holy Spirit in an implicit manner.

- The Father is worshipped ([John 4:23](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&b=Jhn&c=4&v=23&x=66&y=11#conc/23))

> But the hour comes, and now is, when the true worshippers shall worship the Father in spirit and in truth, for the Father seeks such to worship Him.

- The Father is spirit ([John 4:24](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&b=Jhn&c=4&v=23&x=66&y=11#conc/24))

> God is spirit, and those who worship Him must worship in spirit and in truth.

- The Holy Spirit is the Spirit of the Father ([Mark 13:11](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&b=Mar&c=13&v=11&x=0&y=0#conc/11) cp. [Matt. 10:19-20](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&b=Mat&c=10&v=19&x=0&y=0#conc/19)):

> But when they lead and deliver you up, do not worry beforehand about what you shall speak, nor meditate, but whatever shall be given you in that hour, speak that, for it is not you who speak, but the Holy Spirit.
>
> But when they deliver you up, do not worry about how or what you shall speak, for what you shall speak shall be given to you in that same hour. For it is not you who speak, but the Spirit of your Father who speaks in you.

- The Holy Spirit is distinct from the Father ([Matt. 28:19](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&b=Mat&c=28&v=19&x=0&y=0#conc/19)).

> Therefore, go and teach all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit.

If people worship the Father, and the Holy Spirit is the Spirit of the Father, then they must also be worshipping the Holy Spirit when they worship the Father.

Comment: When you say the Father is spirit, is the John 4 reference in regard to the Holy Spirit or the Father?  Isn't it saying the Holy Spirit is God?

Answer (score 4):

## Worshipping the Holy Spirit *is* Worshipping God

If you assume the idea of the trinity, then "worshiping the Holy Spirit" is no different than worshiping either the Father or the Son. In fact, worshiping the Son is no different than worshiping the Father, because in every way, you are worshiping the one and only God.

Worship is a disposition of the heart, an act of submission and adoration. To worship the Holy Spirit would be to thank, praise, submit to, etc. the Holy Spirit, and since the persons of the Godhead act in perfect harmony, you would be simultaneously thanking, praising, submitting to, etc. both the Father and the Son for the exact same thing(s).

Comment: +1 to this, though for explicitly worshipping the holy spirit, I cannot think of a biblical reference.  On the other hand, as mojo has said, it's all the same thing.  The trinity still boggles my mind in a lot of ways, but His thoughts and ways are so higher than ours, I'm not sure as humans we can really make sense of it, even when sometimes we think we do.

Comment: Possibly true, but it begs the question of whether the Bible ever explicitly says that we should worship the Holy Spirit, or whether the early church did so. I mean in the sense that someone would actually name him as an object of worship. For example does anyone in the Bible ever say "Praise you, Holy Spirit" like they would say "Praise God"?

Comment: Is it possible to worship Jesus and not simultaneously worship the Father? I wouldn't think so. The same is true of the Holy Spirit. You cannot worship only one of the persons. You worship God.

Comment: The question asks whether the New Testament mentions worshiping the Holy Spirit as it mentions worshiping the Father and the Son. This doesn't answer that question, but only engages in some general theological reflection on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall ANY passage in the Bible where the Holy Spirit is worshiped, but since the Holy Spirit is equally God as Jesus and the Father are, therefore, He also can be worshiped.

Just because the Bible doesn't (as far as I know) give an example of worship of the Holy Spirit doesn't mean It doesn't permit it.

“We believe in the Holy Spirit, the Lord
....With the Father and the Son
he is worshiped and glorified....”

- Nicaea.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. Your answer goes somewhat beyond the question, which doesn't actually ask whether it's okay to worship the Holy Spirit. It only asks whether the New Testament *mentions* Christians worshiping the Holy Spirit. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 1):

**We are never clearly or directly taught to direct our worship or prayers to the Person of the Holy Spirit.** Though He is fully God and an equal member of the Trinity. There is no jealousy in the Godhead.  But it is frankly a disservice to manipulate trinitarian texts of Scripture to try to make a point for addressing our worship or prayers directly to the Holy Spirit.

Jesus said, "Howbeit when he, the Spirit of truth, is come, he will guide you into all truth: for **he shall not speak of himself**; but whatsoever he shall hear, that shall he speak: and he will shew you things to come." (John 16:13)

The Holy Spirit is the "illuminator" of the Godhead.  He helps us "see" and thus worship the Father and the Son.  He does not point to Himself or draw attention to Himself. Though clearly worthy of worship as part of the Trinity, there is no imperative in the Bible to pray to or worship the Holy Spirit.  We do see "praying in the Spirit," and "singing with the (my) Spirit..."  The believers at Cornelius' house who were filled with the Spirit, worshipped ecstatically and were, "exalting God."

Paul tells us to not be drunk with wine but to be filled with the Spirit...which should motivate and empower us to, speak to one another "in psalms, hymns, and spiritual songs," and to God, "singing and making a melody in your heart to the Lord; always giving thanks for all things in the name of our Lord Jesus Christ to God, even the Father." (Eph 5:18-20)  We need no further clarification on this.

The Holy Spirit clearly has come to direct our worship and prayer to and through Jesus Christ, to God the Father.  This is the very clear teaching of the Scriptures.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  If you'd like to strengthen your answer, I'd recommend adding sources to show that this analysis doesn't merely reflect your opinion.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). It is hard to answer a Biblical basis question with a negative, even if that is the correct answer. I think you've done a reasonable job, but I do agree with @Nathaniel that you haven't provided a Biblical basis for all of the statements you make here.

Answer (score 1):

In Exodus 35, it says:

> 30 Then Moses said to the Israelites, “See, the Lord has chosen
>   Bezalel son of Uri, the son of Hur, of the tribe of Judah, 31 and he
>   has filled him with the Spirit of God, with wisdom, with
>   understanding, with knowledge and with all kinds of skills— 32 to make
>   artistic designs for work in gold, silver and bronze, 33 to cut and
>   set stones, to work in wood and to engage in all kinds of artistic
>   crafts. 34 And he has given both him and Oholiab son of Ahisamak, of
>   the tribe of Dan, the ability to teach others. 35 He has filled them
>   with skill to do all kinds of work as engravers, designers,
>   embroiderers in blue, purple and scarlet yarn and fine linen, and
>   weavers—all of them skilled workers and designers.

Bezalel created the ark of the covenant and other items that were part of the tabernacle, the centerpiece of Israel's worship. According to Jewish tradition (and consistent with the Bible's genealogies), Bezalel was thirteen years old at the time, and Moses marveled that Bezalel was able to create the items exactly as he saw them in his visions, down to details that Moses was not able to express in words. Now Jesus said that we must worship God in Spirit and in truth (John 4:24). This shows the Holy Spirit's central place in the establishment first of Jewish worship practices and then of Christian ones.

What is worship? It is to stand in the glory proceeding from God and reflect it back to him. To glorify something is to laud and praise its excellence. When the Father praises his Son (Mark 1:11, *And a voice came from heaven: "You are my Son, whom I love; with you I am well pleased."*) then he is offering worship to the Son. When the Son praises the Holy Spirit, he is offering worship to the Spirit, and that is what he does when he describes the Holy Spirit's truth-giving ministry (John 16: *But when he, the Spirit of truth, comes, he will guide you into all the truth.*)

In Luke 4:

> Jesus, full of the Holy Spirit, left the Jordan and was led by the
>   Spirit into the wilderness...

If the Holy Spirit is "in" Jesus, and Jesus follows the guidance of the Spirit, it would be idolatry for him to do so unless the Spirit were worthy of worship, since obedience is a part of worship.

In 1 Corinthians 6:19 it says:

> Do you not know that your bodies are temples of the Holy Spirit, who
>   is in you, whom you have received from God? You are not your own...

When you build a temple, it is supposed to be a house where God can dwell. If the Holy Spirit is the one dwelling in the temple where worship is performed, then the Holy Spirit is the one being worshiped.

Answer (score 0):

**The Holy Spirit is wholly God -- totally equal to the Father and the Son in glory, power and majesty. He, being fully God together with the two, is *above* all creation and thus, deserves worship from all creation.**

The Holy Spirit is *implicitly* worshiped in the New Testament Scriptures.

### Prayer is a form of worship

Worship is an offering or sacrifice to God.

> Therefore, I urge you, brothers and sisters, in view of God's mercy,
>   to **offer your bodies** as **a living sacrifice**, holy and pleasing to
>   God--**this is your true and proper worship.** Romans 12:1 (NLT)

Good works are offering or sacrifices to God.

> And don't forget to **do good and to share with those in need**.
>   **These are the sacrifices that please God**. Hebrews 13:6 (NLT)

Prayer is an offering to God.

> Accept **my prayer** as incense **offered to you**, and my upraised
>   hands as an evening offering. Psalm 141:2 (NLT)

Thus, both good works and prayers are forms of worship.

### The Holy Spirit is prayed to

- ### 2 Corinthians 13:14

This passage show us that the Trinity is the object of the *benediction prayer*.

> "The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ and the love of God **and the
>   fellowship of the Holy Spirit** be with you all."
>
> 2 Corinthians 13:14 (ESV)

- ### Matthew 28:19

In baptism, the Trinity is clearly *invoked* (Mt. 28:19).This shows that in baptism, the Trinity is being worshiped. The Holy Spirit is a member of the Trinity. Hence, in baptism the Holy Spirit is worshiped together with the Father and the Son.

> "Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the
>   name of the Father and of the Son **and of the Holy Spirit**."
>
> Matthew 28:19 (ESV)

The N.T. might have not used 'proskuneo' or 'latria' in reference to the Holy Spirit but when they coupled the Holy Spirit with the Father and the Son, the triune tandem shows that , logically, they are equally being worshiped.

### Therefore, the Holy Spirit is worshiped.

Comment: Can you biblically support your assertion that prayer is a part of worship?

Answer (score 0):

Does the Holy Ghost worship the Son? Yes. Do the Son and the Holy Ghost worship the Father? Yes. Does the Father worship the Son? No. Do the Father and Son worship the Holy Ghost? No. **Do we worship or pray to the Holy Ghost? Never.** Not once in Holy Writ does God teach us to do so. The apostles did not believe the doctrine of the trinity as described by a heated debate in the 4th century (e.g. co-equality). So I don't either. (Mark 10:18, John 14:28, John 20:17)

Comment: Welcome!  Unfortunately, this post reads more like a rant against a doctrine than an actual answer to the question. [This is a Q&A site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), not a discussion forum, so the best answers focus on the question asked, not merely related subjects. I hope you'll take the [tour] and check out some of the other questions and answers we have here!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That was a nice way of responding to my comment. I did not mean it as a rant and should have written it differently.  My main point is that the New Testament does not mention Christians worshipping the Holy Spirit.